# Google Drive API (.NET) - Transfer ownership from Service Account to Domain user

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I am creating file on Google drive with [.NET client API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/) with Service account.

```
    string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
    GoogleCredential credential;
    using (var stream = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Resources/GoogleCredentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(scopes);
    }
    DriveService drive = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    });
```

I succesfully create file,

```
    var f = drive.Files;
    var request = f.Create(new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
    {
        Name = "Test from ASP.NET Core",
        AppProperties = prop,
        MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
    });
    var file = await request.ExecuteAsync();
```

share it with all domain, but I can not transfer ownership to a domain user.

```
    Permission permission = new Permission()
    {
        EmailAddress = "user@example.com",
        Type = "user",
        Domain = "example.com",
        Role = "owner"
    };
    var requestpermission = drive.Permissions.Create(permission, file.Id);
    requestpermission.TransferOwnership = true;
    var perm = await requestpermission.ExecuteAsync();
```

I get error:

> The specified domain is invalid or not applicable for the given
>   permission type.

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910935/google-drive-api-transfer-ownership-from-service-account), but using p12 cert file is not recommended. So I want to use JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ownership transfers can only be done between users in the same domain, and service accounts don't belong to any domain. You're best option may be to create a Team Drive that the service account has access to, and perform a two stage process:

1. Use the service account to move the file into the team drive. `Files.update` with the `addParents` parameter set to the Team Drive ID.
2. Use the domain user to move the file out of the team drive. `Files.update` with the `addParents` parameter set to `root` (or some target folder's ID) and the `removeParents` parameter set to the Team Drive ID.