# Google Drive API V3: Creating file permissions for a domain

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, file-permissions

Trying to add permissions to a file via Google Drive's API V3 and I ran into the error below. I want to allow requests from mta.io, my site, to able to read the file. The error seems to come from what domain I pass in the body of request for example, example.com works fine and permissions are granted to it. Do I need to whitelist my domain in order to give it permissions to the file?

Works:

```
{
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "domain",
  "domain": "example.com"
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
{
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "domain",
  "domain": "mta.io"
}
```

Error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "The specified domain is invalid or not applicable for the given permission type.",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "permission.domain"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The specified domain is invalid or not applicable for the given permission type."
 }
}
```

I'm using the [try it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create#try-it) feature found on the API's site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, you can only use G Suite domains.
It is a bummer but in order to share file permission exclusively with a domain you need to have a G Suite account and verify that you own that domain - the domain needs to be linked with your G Suite account.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-permissions#types_and_values

> For example, a permission with a type of domain may have a domain of thecompany.com, indicating that the permission grants the given role to all users in the G Suite domain thecompany.com

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750785/google-drive-api-net-transfer-ownership-from-service-account-to-domain-user), this can only be done between users in the same domain, and service accounts don't belong to any domain.

> You're best option may be to create a Team Drive that the service account has access to, and perform a two stage process:
>
> 1. Use the service account to move the file into the team drive. [`Files.update`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update) with the `addParents` parameter set to the Team Drive ID.
> 2. Use the domain user to move the file out of the team drive. [`Files.update`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update) with the `addParents` parameter set to `root` (or some target folder's ID) and the `removeParents` parameter set to the Team Drive ID.

Here's another SO post which might also help: [Google Drive SDK - change item sharing permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917828/google-drive-sdk-change-item-sharing-permissions)